# having count linq in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have a SQL query which returns repeating fields to keep track of operations.

```
SELECT contratosfianzas.adquisicion_contrato, count(*) as no_ope 
From contratosfianzas 
GROUP BY contratosfianzas.adquisicion_contrato 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

I tried with the examples shown here but I always return 1.

Could you please help me.

In advance thank you very much

Comment: You need a `Where` after the `Group`.

Comment: But in linq for VB how can i "translate"

Answer (score 0):

```
from b in db.contratosfianzas
group b by b.adquisicion_contrato into grup
where grup.Count() > 1
select grup.Key, grup.Count()
```